Why are cell factory and cell value factory not loading in table cells?
I am working on a project where I have to load text from a database to my application's tableview. With my little knowledge I generated a minimal reproducible example similar to my problem. The example I provide is quite large but this is what I managed to make it that much smaller.
Main problem: Table cells are not showing any content. I have no clue why this is happening. Is it because of TableCell or TableColumn? I have no idea.
I read solutions and documentations related to my problem, but none of them worked on this case.
Javafx PropertyValueFactory not populating Tableview
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html
HelloController.java
public class HelloController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TableView<myModel> tableView;
    @FXML private Button insertData;

    TableColumn<myModel, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("FirstName");
    TableColumn<myModel, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("LastName");
    TableColumn<myModel, Button> buttonCol = new TableColumn<>("");

    static ObservableList<myModel> creds = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        try {
            myModel.createTable(connectToDB(), "mytable");
        }
        catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Table Exists");
            try{
                myModel.showTable(connectToDB(), "mytable");
            }
            catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tableView.setItems(creds);

        insertData.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    myModel.insertTable(connectToDB(), "Hrthik", "Bhowmik");
                } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, buttonCol);

    }

    public void loadDBToTable() {

        creds.add(new myModel(myModel.getFirstName(), myModel.getLastName()));

        System.out.println(myModel.getFirstName() +"\t"+ myModel.getLastName());

//        Tried but not working
//        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> myModel.firstNameProperty());
//        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> myModel.lastNameProperty());
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(myModel.firstNameProperty().getName()));
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(myModel.lastNameProperty().getName()));
        buttonCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<myModel, Button>, TableCell<myModel, Button>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<myModel, Button> call(TableColumn<myModel, Button> myModelStringTableColumn) {
                final TableCell<myModel, Button> cell = new TableCell<myModel, Button>() {
                    private final Button button = new Button("Remove");
                    {
                        button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                            System.out.println("Remove this row from TableView and Database");
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Button item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(button);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });
    }

    private Connection connectToDB() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:MY_DATA.db");
        System.out.println("Database connection success");
        return con;
    }
}


myModel.java
public class myModel {

    static HelloController controller = new HelloController();

    private static StringProperty firstName;
    private static StringProperty lastName;

    public myModel(String firstName, String lastName) {
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
    }

    public static StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        if (firstName == null) firstName = new SimpleStringProperty("firstname");
        return firstName;
    }
    public static String getFirstName() {
        return firstNameProperty().get();
    }
    public static void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
    }

    public static StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        if (lastName == null) lastName = new SimpleStringProperty("lastname");
        return myModel.lastName;
    }
    public static String getLastName() {
        return lastNameProperty().get();
    }
    public static void setLastName(String lastName) {
        lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
    }

    //Sql part
    public static void createTable(Connection con, String tableName) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement command = con.prepareStatement(
                "CREATE TABLE "+ tableName + "( FirstName varchar(50), LastName varchar(50));");
        command.execute();
        command.close();
        System.out.println("Table created successfully");
    }

    public static void insertTable(Connection con, String firstName, String lastName) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?,?);");
        insert.setString(1, firstName);
        insert.setString(2, lastName);
        insert.execute();
        insert.close();
        System.out.println("Insertion complete");
    }

    public static void showTable(Connection con, String tableName) throws SQLException {
        Statement cmd = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet show = cmd.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tableName+";");
        while(show.next()) {
            System.out.println(show.getString("FirstName") +"\t"+ show.getString("LastName"));

            myModel.setFirstName(show.getString("FirstName"));
            myModel.setLastName(show.getString("LastName"));

            controller.loadDBToTable();
        }
        cmd.close();
    }
}

hello-view.fxml
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="375.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.minumal_.HelloController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tableView" layoutX="3.0" layoutY="7.0" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="294.0" />
      <Button fx:id="insertData" layoutX="309.0" layoutY="27.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Insert" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>




Maybe I am missing it, but I don't see anywhere where you are calling loadDBToTable().

Off-topic: don't use PropertyValueFactory

Also off-topic: why is so much of this static? That really doesn't make sense. Why does your table item model class create an instance of your controller class? Models should know nothing at all about controllers. None of this really makes sense.

@James_D loadDBToTable() is called in showTable() function which is under myModel class. This is the reason why i created instance of controller class in model class to access the loadDBToTable(). And the showTable() is calling in initialize(). The reason of using static is to use those function without creating any object of myModel() class. Because if I create (myModel model = new myModel(parameter requires);) this don't have any idea about what will be the parameters here.

@James_D Also used                                                                                                            firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<myModel, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {      public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<myModel, String> p) {          return p.getValue().firstNameProperty();      }   });  }        this does not work

There are just a lot of problems here, one or two minor fixes won’t make it work  I advise you get your table to display data correctly first using some hard coded data, no database code at all (no fxml either) there are tutorials available on that.  You can add more complexity and functionality gradually once the basics work.

*"i created instance of controller class in model class to access the loadDBToTable()". But that means you are not calling loadDBToTable() on the controller (the object created by the FXMLLoader), you are just calling it on an arbitrary object that happens to be the same type.

"The reason of using static is to use those function without creating any object of myModel() class." But now every row in the table will display the same data. How does this make sense?

"Because if I create (myModel model = new myModel(parameter requires);) this don't have any idea about what will be the parameters here." So surely the sensible conclusion is to load the data in a different class, instead of breaking the model class. As suggested in another comment, start by getting the table working with hard-coded data and no database. Then write code that just retrieves and stores data in a database, with no user interface at all. Only when you have both of those pieces working should you write code that integrates them.

"Also used ... this does not work". I know that doesn't fix the problem. That's why I said it was off-topic. I was just commenting that firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().firstNameProperty()); was better, for numerous reasons (enumerated in the link provided earlier). The problem is caused by code you have written than indicates you don't fully understand classes, objects, the relationship between them, and what the static keyword does. I recommend getting a reasonable understanding of Java basics before trying to uses a moderately complex library like JavaFX.

@James_D I successfully made those table cells working. It was shameful mistake of mine. Now another issue occurs, all columns are returning same values. So, should i remove all static keyword from myModel class. And how i am gonna use it's function after that. Or should i create another class to load the data from database but how. Please provide me an easy path. It would be very helpful on my learning.

@James_D After 30 minutes of searching and trying I'm finally able to display all data from database in tableview. I used PropertyValueFactory<>() and little changes in myModel class to done this job. But you recommended to avoid PropertyValueFactory<>(). And I'm still interested to do this again in your way. Please share your knowledge, i'm willing to learn.

First mistake, I made is not calling loadDBToTable() method in my FXMLController, that is why those columns are not displaying. Properties in loadDBToTable() belongs to FXMLController, by calling this method in another class will not work fine.
Second mistake is that, I made all of my methods and variables static in myModel class. That is why table columns are displaying same values. By simply removing static keyword and adding a overridden constructor I temporarily solved this issue. By this way I can also make an object of this class and access it's methods. This doesn't seems flexible to me.
I moved SQL part from myModel class to HelloController class. This also can be done by moving another class.
HelloController.java
public class HelloController implements Initializable {

@FXML private TableView<myModel> tableView;
@FXML private Button insertData;

TableColumn<myModel, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("FirstName");
TableColumn<myModel, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("LastName");
TableColumn<myModel, Button> buttonCol = new TableColumn<>("");

static ObservableList<myModel> creds = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

myModel model = new myModel();

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    try {
        createTable(connectToDB(), "mytable");
    }
    catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Table Exists");
        try{
            showTable(connectToDB(), "mytable");
            loadDBToTable();
        }
        catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    tableView.setItems(creds);

    insertData.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                insertTable(connectToDB(), "Hrthik", "Bhowmik");
                insertTable(connectToDB(), "otherFirst", "otherLast");
                insertTable(connectToDB(), "AnotherFirst", "AnotherLast");
            } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    tableView.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, buttonCol);

}

public void loadDBToTable() {

    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().firstNameProperty());
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().lastNameProperty());

    buttonCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<myModel, Button>, TableCell<myModel, Button>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<myModel, Button> call(TableColumn<myModel, Button> myModelStringTableColumn) {
            final TableCell<myModel, Button> cell = new TableCell<myModel, Button>() {
                private final Button button = new Button("Remove");
                {
                    button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                        System.out.println("Remove this row from TableView and Database");
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Button item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(button);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
}

public Connection connectToDB() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:MY_DATA.db");
    System.out.println("Database connection success");
    return con;
}

//Sql part
public void createTable(Connection con, String tableName) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement command = con.prepareStatement(
            "CREATE TABLE "+ tableName + "( FirstName varchar(50), LastName varchar(50));");
    command.execute();
    command.close();
    System.out.println("Table created successfully");
}

public void insertTable(Connection con, String firstName, String lastName) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?,?);");
    insert.setString(1, firstName);
    insert.setString(2, lastName);
    insert.execute();
    insert.close();
    System.out.println("Insertion complete");
}

public void showTable(Connection con, String tableName) throws SQLException {
    Statement cmd = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet show = cmd.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tableName+";");
    while(show.next()) {
        System.out.println(show.getString("FirstName") +"\t"+ show.getString("LastName"));
        model.setFirstName(show.getString("FirstName"));
        model.setLastName(show.getString("LastName"));
        creds.add(new myModel(model.getFirstName(), model.getLastName()));
        System.out.println(model.getFirstName() +"\t"+ model.getLastName());
    }
    cmd.close();
}}

static keyword removed and new overridden constructor added.
myModel.java
public class myModel {

private StringProperty firstName;
private StringProperty lastName;

static HelloController controller = new HelloController();
//myModel model = new myModel();

public myModel(String firstName, String lastName) {
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
}

public myModel() {
    System.out.println(getFirstName() +"\t"+ getLastName()); //They are null at first stage, if null then set to firstname and lastname
}

public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
    if (firstName == null) firstName = new SimpleStringProperty("firstname");
    return firstName;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstNameProperty().get();
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
}

public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
    if (lastName == null) lastName = new SimpleStringProperty("lastname");
    return lastName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastNameProperty().get();
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
}
}

And never touched the fxml file.
That's it.

